# java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException with JUnitParamsRunner

Tags: java, junit

I have some test class:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class TempTest {
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DateTime frozenDateTime = new DateTime( 2018, 10, 22, 0, 0, 0 );
        DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed( frozenDateTime.getMillis());
    }
    @After
    public void unfreeze(){
        DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisSystem();
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters({
            "testFile"
    })
    public void testRender(String docName) {
        try {
            MyService myService = new MyService();
            myService.processFile(docName);   // this I have java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException 
            Assert.assertTrue(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Assert.assertTrue(false);
        }
    }
}
```

but it is happens when I run my test without debug if I run test in debug mode and go step by step all is fine.
It is exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlObjectBase.build_text(XmlObjectBase.java:882)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.ensureOccupancy(Xobj.java:1712)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.disconnectUser(Xobj.java:1429)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.moveNode(Cur.java:1960)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Cur.moveNode(Cur.java:1846)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.removeElement(Xobj.java:2213)
    at org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.store.Xobj.remove_element(Xobj.java:2236)
    at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.impl.CTBodyImpl.removeP(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement(XWPFDocument.java:949)
```

What is wrong in my test?

Comment: Can you post exception occured during test without debugging and your service logic, it is hard to defy from this and also where did you initialized your service in test class??

Comment: How is `myService` known? Possibly you lack an injection of the instance.

Comment: @Mär I'm update my post. I instantiate myService in this test.

Comment: Logic on this method very simple I'm insert new XWPFParagraph after last paragraph and than remove all empty paragraphs. And if I go step by step in debug all fine but if I run without debug I have exception.

Comment: @John  Do you find an answer? I have the same trouble when I call XWPFDocument.removeBodyElement.